# Share session variables between asp.net and vb6

Tags: asp.net, vb6, session-variables

Hi i have a question about Session variables, i want to call in GET via ajax, from my .aspx page, a page .asp that have VB6 code inside, i need to share Session variables between them actually i tried this:

ASPX file

```
<html>
<head>
<title>let's try Ajax</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var request = $.ajax({
            url: "/Default.asp",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "html",
            cache: "false"
        });


        request.done(function(msg){

            $("#insert").html(msg);

        });
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        in the aspx: <%Response.Write(Session["try"].ToString()); %>

    </div>
<div id="insert">

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

code behind page:

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["try"] = "hello world";
    }
}
```

finally .asp page

```
<%
  [...]
  Response.Write  "" & Session("try")
  Response.End 
  [...]
%>
```

Actually the Session doesn't show anything in the .asp page, but in the .aspx page shows it's string inside, what's wrong with my code? Is it possible to pass share a session?

Comment: Not really sure what you are trying to achieve, I have used VB6 for windows development not sure why you need session value here. If you just want to share values store it in Database and access it from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you want to share your session between Class ASP and ASP.Net. so you need to store 
your session information in SQL server. Please refer below link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479313.aspx

Comment: This is the only way to share session?

Comment: @theLaw In your case, you are calling asp page through Ajax otherwise you can collection all session variable information and crate hidden variables to POST those to Class ASP and do the reverse means create session variable from hidden variable on Classic ASP

Comment: @ManojMevada +1 for good explanation .. just an advice dont put only links .. put some ref code too